# Make links around images unclickable using CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup **which I can't change**.

```
<a href="link-to-somepage.html"><img src="link-to-image.jpg"></a>
```

Is there any way for me to make these images unclickable? i have tried setting `pointer-events` to `none` on `img` but that does not work. Setting them to `none` on all `a` tags will make every link unclickable.

Is there some way for me to make only the links around images unclickable? I would prefer a CSS based solution, if one exists. :)

Comment: imho you won't find a css based solution yet. There is the `:has` and afaik also a parent selector as draft, but they are not final and not supported by current browsers yet.

Comment: Need the surrounding HTML to give you a CSS answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't change the markup so try to use **[jQuery](https://jquery.com/)**. Get all images and after that all `a` tags which are the immediate parent of the `images`. And by using `click` event handler [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

```
$('img').parent('a').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
})
```

or as was said by **@t.niese**  in the comments you can also use

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:has(>img)' function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    });
```

For more you can see example

```js
$('img').parent('a').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='www.google.com'>Google1</a> 
<br/>
<a href='google.com'><img src='https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png' alt='an image'>Google 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks suren :). I will accept this answer if no one else can provide a CSS based solution.

Comment: I would write it using event delegation (`$(document).on('click', 'a:has(>img)'`, ...)`), because then it would always work, even if the DOM is mondified after the script was executed.

Comment: @t.niese agree with you

Comment: @t.niese Yeah that's the correct answer here anyway Suren add css solution `pointer-events: none` that's also prevent click by css but also change cursor icon as well.

Comment: Although it wasn't specified in the question, I'd be tempted to account for the case where an `<a>` contains text *and* an image. Both versions offered here would prevent the link bring clicked at all, it might be desirable to be able to click the text but not the image

Comment: Regardless of my point, this answer does offer the best solution to the question as it was asked. So it gets my +1

Comment: Will this solution still work if the markup is loaded via AJAX?

Comment: @NeenaVivek the `document.on()` case will

Answer (score 3):

You could do like this, where you `float` the image in combination with `pointer-events: none`

As the image is floated its parent will collapse to size 0 because of a [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) is established, and the anchor won't grow with its content unless you create a [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) on it.

```css
a > img {
  float:left;
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="alert('click');"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
```

If you gonna use this with flowed text, like below, you'll need to wrap it in a `span`.

```css
a > img {
  float:left;
  pointer-events: none
}
span {
  display: inline-block;  /*  needed if its gonna be flowed with text  */
}
```

```html
Hey, here is a link with an image <span>

<a href="#" onclick="alert('click');"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x30"></a>

</span>, one which can't be clicked on
```

Comment: Really nice approach, though that solution may not fit the layout.

Comment: @connexo Thanks, and you are right, so I added a 2:nd sample, showing how to make it flow properly when used in for example a normal text

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by CSS class also just use that class on anchor tag which you don't want to get clicked like

```
.no-click{
    pointer-events : none !important;
}

<a class="no-click" href="link-to-somepage.html"><img src="link-to-image.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to select a parent based on it's child in CSS at present. Since you cannot change your markup, JavaScript seems to be the only way.

You want to select all the anchor tags whose immediate child is an image. In order to accomplish this,

1. You will have to first select all the img tags whose parent is an anchor tag
2. Loop through each selected img tag
3. Get the handle of it's parent node (which is an anchor tag)
4. change the value of href attribute to "#"

Below is a pure JavaScript solution:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("a > img");
var a;
for(var i=0; i < imgs.length; i++){
  a = imgs[i].parentNode;
  a.href = "#";
}
```

Comment: Clicking a link with `href="#"` will still have a noticeable effect on the page. If you really want to omit the links, then go `a.href = "javascript:void(0);"`.